# chrome.scripting.executeScript fails to run on preexisting tabs with `tabs` and `<all_urls>` host permission

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I have a chrome MV3 extension that has the following manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "permissions": [
    "scripting",
    "tabs"
  ],
  "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"]
}
```

When I install the extension and have existing tabs, I am unable to execute scripts on those existing tabs:

```
chrome.scripting.executeScript({
  target: {tabId: 1305686273}, 
  func: function(){ console.log('hi'); }
});
```

I get this error in my background service worker script:

> Cannot access contents of the page. Extension manifest must request permission to access the respective host.

My understanding is that the `tabs` permission lets me query all tabs without user gesture, and the `"host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"]` should let me execute scripts on all tabs without user gesture.

Am I wrong, or is there something missing to allow scripting on pages without user gesture?

P.S. running `chrome.tabs.get(1305686273).then(console.log)` works as expected.

Comment: @ThomasMueller thanks, i've rephrased the question to focus on preexisting tabs, and left an answer I've tested out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74319499/1166285

Answer (score 5):

`chrome.scripting` seems to throw this error for tabs that existed prior to installing the extension.

> Cannot access contents of the page. Extension manifest must request permission to access the respective host.

Scripting works as expected for any newly created tab, regardless of if the user has clicked the extension.

I've found a workaround is to call `chrome.tabs.reload(tabId)` on those preexisting tabs, and then `chrome.scripting` will work as expected.

Going to raise a bug with the chrome team.

Comment: It may happen if the tab has an iframe with a URL chrome-extension:// of another extension.

Comment: @wOxxOm it's happening for many domains, none of them have iframes, nor `chrome-extension://` URLs within the page.

Answer (score 1):

I've tested it and can't reproduce it. Please post the extensions you are using.

1. Open tab1 and tab2 without installing extensions.
   [image]
2. Install extensions.
   [image]

manifest.json

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "hoge",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "scripting"
  ],
  "host_permissions": [
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  }
}
```

background.js

```js
chrome.tabs.query({ url: "https://*/*" }, (tabs) => {
  for (const { id } of tabs) {
    console.log("tabId=" + id);
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
      target: { tabId: id },
      func: function () { console.log('hi'); }
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Which Chrome version are you using?

I can't reproduce your problem on Manjaro Linux, with Chromium Version 107.0.5304.87 (Official Build) Arch Linux (64-Bit).

1. Start Chrome
2. Open [Manjaro.org](https://manjaro.org/) and [CNN.com](https://www.cnn.com/) and [Stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/)
3. Open chrome://extensions/
4. Disable all extensions
5. Load the the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) below
6. Open the consoles for all tabs, except chrome://extensions/
7. Every console shows the text "hi"

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "executeScript",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },  
    "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"],
    "permissions": [
        "scripting",
        "tabs"
    ]
}
```

background.js

```
(async () => {
    let tabs = await chrome.tabs.query({});
    console.log(tabs);
    tabs.forEach(tab => {
        if (!tab.url.startsWith("chrome://")) {
            console.log(tab.url, "1");
            chrome.scripting.executeScript({
                target: {tabId: tab.id}, 
                func: function() { console.log('hi'); }
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(`executeScript failed on ${tab.id} ${tab.url}`, error);
            }); 
            console.log(tab.url, "2");
        }
    });
})();
```

Comment: hmm that's odd, i'm not sure what other conditions are needed to reproduce.  I'm on `107.0.5304.87 (Official Build) (arm64)`

Comment: Did you run my MCVE and get the same results as with your code?

Comment: your `executeScript` doesn't have a `catch`. I've updated your answer, and can still repro with your MCVE. Your console log of `"2"` runs synchronously regardless of the `executeScript` success/failure